# How to label items in a string column by conditional regex in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

In Polars, I'm working with a DataFrame with messy string data in a column. In this example, the column can contain a phone number, email address, state, zip code, etc. (my real data actually has a hundred or more different "patterns" stored in this column that is a million rows long.)

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "data": [
            "123-123-1234",
            "someone@email.com",
            "345-345-3456",
            "456-456-4567",
            "12345",
            "charlie.brown@peanuts.org",
            "345-345-3456",
            "CA",
            "UT",
        ]
    }
)
```

I am trying to label each item based on a regular expression. For example, "if it looks like a phone number, label it PHONE; if it looks like an email, label it EMAIL; etc.". The result should look something like this...

```
shape: (9, 2)
┌───────────────────────────┬──────────┐
│ data                      ┆ label    │
│ ---                       ┆ ---      │
│ str                       ┆ str      │
╞═══════════════════════════╪══════════╡
│ 123-123-1234              ┆ PHONE    │
│ someone@email.com         ┆ EMAIL    │
│ 345-345-3456              ┆ PHONE    │
│ 456-456-4567              ┆ PHONE    │
│ 12345                     ┆ ZIP CODE │
│ charlie.brown@peanuts.org ┆ EMAIL    │
│ 345-345-3456              ┆ PHONE    │
│ CA                        ┆ STATE    │
│ UT                        ┆ STATE    │
└───────────────────────────┴──────────┘
```

---

My first attempt was simply to do multiple `str.replace` in line...

```py
df.with_columns(
    (
        pl.col("data")
        .str.replace(".*@.*", "EMAIL")
        .str.replace(f"\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d", "PHONE")
        .str.replace(f"\d\d\d\d\d", "ZIP CODE")
        .str.replace(f"^[A-Z][A-Z]$", "STATE")
    ).alias("label")
)
```

This is one way to get the result, except when scaled to *many* `str.replace` (I have over a hundred regex expresses I'm trying to label for a column over a million rows) it is quite slow because it is rerunning the replace method so many times. I am hoping there is a different approach in Polars that can make this much faster that I haven't thought about yet. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: First approach that comes to mind is: `.with_columns(label = pl.coalesce(pl.when(pl.col("data").str.contains(pattern)).then(pl.lit(label)) for pattern, label in ...)` - Polars should run them all in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to coalesce! This is a clever way to handle this. In my real-world example (5million rows and 200 regex patterns to search) this took ~25 seconds. (In my comparison, my lengthy str.replace method was about two minutes)

Comment: Not bad. Apparently the rust regex crate has a [RegexSet](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/#example-match-multiple-regular-expressions-simultaneously) to test multiple patterns at the same time. Would be interesting to find out the fastest way to do this.

Comment: I was curious and tested a RegexSet version. It runs much slower (~10x) compared to when/then. (tested with 2million rows, 400 patterns) So I think that can be ruled out.

Comment: @jqurious what did you use as sample data and patterns?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I couldn't find any "public regex testsuites" so I resorted to concatting the given example. Also with some added variations e.g. `pl.concat(df_re.with_columns(pl.all() + (letter * times)) for times in range(2) for letter in string.ascii_letters)`. When using regexset only a single CPU is maxed out whereas with when/then all CPUs are maxed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got 5 million rows and a lot of them are duplicates then I think you want to make a lookup table with the unique values first then join the original to the lookup table. That way the regex engine doesn't have to work as hard.

I don't want to steal jqurious's answer but coalesce/when seems to be faster using some randomized data than the concat/filter. That said, I think the idea of a lookup table is still valid if there are a lot of repetitions. My random data was unique to start with and I didn't experiment with duplicates so it doesn't say anything about the lookup table.

```
patterns=[(".*@.*", "EMAIL"),
(f"\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d", "PHONE"),
(f"\d\d\d\d\d", "ZIP CODE"),
(f"^[A-Z][A-Z]$", "STATE")]

lookups = df.unique('data').lazy()
lookups = pl.concat([
    lookups.filter(pl.col('data').str.contains(x[0])).with_columns(label=pl.lit(x[1]))
    for x in patterns
    ]).collect()
df.join(lookups, on='data')
shape: (9, 2)
┌───────────────────────────┬──────────┐
│ data                      ┆ label    │
│ ---                       ┆ ---      │
│ str                       ┆ str      │
╞═══════════════════════════╪══════════╡
│ 123-123-1234              ┆ PHONE    │
│ someone@email.com         ┆ EMAIL    │
│ 345-345-3456              ┆ PHONE    │
│ 456-456-4567              ┆ PHONE    │
│ 12345                     ┆ ZIP CODE │
│ charlie.brown@peanuts.org ┆ EMAIL    │
│ 345-345-3456              ┆ PHONE    │
│ CA                        ┆ STATE    │
│ UT                        ┆ STATE    │
└───────────────────────────┴──────────┘
```

Another idea would be to do a one (or two) splits of the data rather than pushing it all through and relying on parallelism. Ideally you could choose a label which will have a lot of matches, let's say STATE has the most matches:

```
splits = (
    df.unique()
    .with_columns(is_state=pl.col('data').str.contains("^[A-Z][A-Z]$"))
    .partition_by('is_state', as_dict=True, include_key=False)
)
lookups = splits[True].with_columns(label=pl.lit('STATE'))
## Then finish the rest of the data as above
lookups = pl.concat([lookups.lazy()] + [
    splits[False].lazy()
    .filter(pl.col('data').str.contains(x[0])).with_columns(label=pl.lit(x[1]))
    for x in patterns if x[1]!='STATE'
]).collect()
df.join(lookups, on='data')
```

This splitting approach will only be beneficial if there are **both** a lot of rows in total **and** if you can pick out a pattern/label that covers a significant portion of the total rows. What the numbers are on that, you'll have to experiment with.

Comment: Wow; this is amazing. In my real example, I have 250 regex/label pairs, 24,000 unique values in the "data" column, and the height of my df is almost 5 million rows. This "lookup-table/join" approach (no splitting) took less than a second.

Comment: Wow yeah lucky guess that there'd be a lot of duplicates. Anytime you can shrink a problem by 200x, it's going to have good results.

Answer (score 2):

The initial approach that comes to mind is to use a
`pl.when().then()` for each pattern.

Polars runs them all in parallel and [`pl.coalesce`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html#polars-coalesce) can choose the first non-null result.

It can be common in these cases for a regex to be a "subset" of a longer pattern, so you usually want them sorted by length (descending).

```py
df_re.sort(pl.col("pattern").str.len_chars()).reverse()
```

```py
┌──────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ label    ┆ pattern                │
│ ---      ┆ ---                    │
│ str      ┆ str                    │
╞══════════╪════════════════════════╡
│ PHONE    ┆ \d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d │
│ STATE    ┆ ^[A-Z][A-Z]$           │
│ ZIP CODE ┆ \d\d\d\d\d             │
│ EMAIL    ┆ .*@.*                  │
└──────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

```py
patterns = df_re.sort(pl.col("pattern").str.len_chars()).reverse().iter_rows()

choices = [
    pl.when(pl.col("data").str.contains(pattern))  
      .then(pl.lit(label))
    for label, pattern in patterns
]

df.with_columns(label = pl.coalesce(choices))
```

```
shape: (9, 2)
┌───────────────────────────┬──────────┐
│ data                      ┆ label    │
│ ---                       ┆ ---      │
│ str                       ┆ str      │
╞═══════════════════════════╪══════════╡
│ 123-123-1234              ┆ PHONE    │
│ someone@email.com         ┆ EMAIL    │
│ 345-345-3456              ┆ PHONE    │
│ 456-456-4567              ┆ PHONE    │
│ 12345                     ┆ ZIP CODE │
│ charlie.brown@peanuts.org ┆ EMAIL    │
│ 345-345-3456              ┆ PHONE    │
│ CA                        ┆ STATE    │
│ UT                        ┆ STATE    │
└───────────────────────────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks @jquirious for expanding on this approach beyond your original comment in the question. Sorting the regex patterns did improve the performance for me. With sorting, my real example took 13 seconds, without sorting took 23 seconds. I'm glad I know what coalese does now.